# How to see all used classes during runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

Suppose there is a huge Java project and the entire execution is unknown throughout the classes. Is there a way to see all used classes list during runtime using some Eclipse feature?

For example:
Main.java -> someClass1.java -> someClass2.java -> ...

Ps: I know about debug tab, but I guess It only works in this way when you know at least one class and put a breakpoint inside there. This is not my case.

Ps: I don't know if this affects or helps, but this project uses BndTools (implementation of OSGI).

Comment: java -verbose:class. Look here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/ (great bender)

Comment: Rename a class, build the app. Check for build problems. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Is Java code coverage what you are looking for? https://www.eclemma.org/